# htaccess 301 Redirects dont seem to be working for me

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im having some issues trying to work out some redirects so here is what im needing:

i have changed a url and need to setup r=301 for the following

/folder-path-old/file-name-old.html to /folder-path-new/file-name-new.html
/folder-path-old/file-name-old/product-no-change.html to /folder-path-new/file-name-new/product-no-change.html

i guess the second could use a wildcard of some sort as the files within the new path  have not change... any thoughts?

what i tried so far:

```
RewriteRule /bean-bags/category-bean-bags.html /bean-bags/category.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/bean-bags/category-bean-bags/(.*)$  /bean-bags/category/$1  [R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^bean-bags/category-bean-bags/(.*)$  /bean-bags/category/$1?  [R,L]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: For which URL id it not work and what is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: actually i wrote it wrong, the rule works, i change the file to file redirect to use redirect 301 but adds ?sef_rewrite=1 at the end of the url

Comment: Also I edited my answer to strip out any existing query string.

Comment: Ending with a ? says to suppress any Query String. Using the [QSA] flag says to append any existing Query String to the URL (if you have your own Query String in the rewrite). Using neither adds an existing Query String *only* if there is not already a Query String in the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mod_alias instead:

```
Redirect 301 /bean-bags/category-bean-bags.html /bean-bags/category.html
Redirect 301 /bean-bags/category-bean-bags/ /bean-bags/category/
```

Comment: when i use the redirect 301 i get ?sef_rewrite=1 at the end